# BeautifulSoup doesn't work with curl output

Tags: python, curl, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the list of files with timestamp (date) from my jrog artifactory through python code.
I am using BeautifulSoup python package to get the particular details. but its failing to read the data from curl output. please suggest.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

output = os.system('curl -X GET "http://myjfrog.cricinfo.com:8082/artifactory/generic-local/"')
soup = BeautifulSoup(output, 'html.parser')
print (soap.title)
```

but i am getting below error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head><meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
<title>Index of generic-local/</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of generic-local/</h1>
<pre>Name        Last modified      Size</pre><hr/>
<pre><a href="1.sh">1.sh</a>         24-Jul-2020 06:51    -
<a href="ec2.py">ec2.py</a>       24-Jul-2020 06:46  3.11 KB
<a href="passwd">passwd</a>       21-Jul-2020 13:47  1.29 KB
<a href="s3_test.py">s3_test.py</a>   21-Jul-2020 13:08  94 bytes
<a href="zoo.sh">zoo.sh</a>       24-Jul-2020 06:52    -
</pre>
<hr/><address style="font-size:small;">Artifactory/7.6.3 Server at localhost Port 8081</address></body></html>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./2_repo.py", line 7, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(output, 'html.parser')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 307, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) the return value is the exit status not the command ouput, you can either use subprocess & preferably ``request`` module as shown in below answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with how you use `os.system`, as the return value is the exit status of the process. Hence the type error.

You can check that in the Python console:

```
import os
output = os.system('curl google.com')
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
100   219  100   219    0     0   2737      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2737
print(output)
0
```

If you want to stick to executing a command in a subshell, the `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using `os.system()`.

Or, just go with `requests`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://google.com").text, "html.parser").title.text
```

This prints `Google`.

By the way, you have a typo in your code. You have `soup` but then you do `soap.title`